# Flutter error - Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI nullapi/auth/login/

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart-null-safety, null-safety

Fairly new to Flutter and have encountered an issue. I am trying to get the emulator (for both iOS and Android) of my app to connect to an API that is running on my local machine. I had it working up until I upgraded flutter null-safety and have not been able to get it back since. Any suggestions on how I can fix the error I am getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear about that - you are trying to access the URI without a host. The line with the URI path looks like  `nullapi/auth/login/` I assume it should not start from `null`.

The part of the code you provided us with in question is not clear regarding the error because the error clearly appears when you try to call `api/auth/login/` but there is nothing regarding this call in the code you provided.

The issue is that your `apiURL` is null. At which point it becomes null - that I don't know - the code in question is not enough to figure it out. I would suggest you debug the whole data flow - from parsing to the actual call, and, I am sure of it, you will be able to find the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I omitted that piece of code unintentionally from this post but have since update it. The code the URI it is trying to access is : 

static const LOGIN_PATH = 'api/auth/login/';

Being new to flutter, I am not sure how to troubleshoot this. Do you have a resource you can share with me to help me along my way? thank you

Comment: also, when I run the same code with --no-sound-null-safety, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: One again, the code you provided is not sufficient to figure out the issue. I suggest you to [debug](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/debugging) the app - this way you will be aware of all of the changes on every step. You can also upload the app to some public repo and I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added json file to your assets in `pubspec.yaml` file ? like below

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - locale/en.json
```

Add file json and rebuild the app

Comment: thanks for contributing, can you provide an explanation as to why this would fix my issue?

Comment: Whenever you are working with any external files like json or wanted any external resource to be used you need to specify it in your pubspec.yaml file. this will add more light to it. 
https://suragch.medium.com/reading-configuration-files-and-settings-in-flutter-and-dart-cc14bbd93698

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that my environment file did not specify all the variables required to properly build the application, which resulted in null variables.

After configuring these variables to allow them to be nullable, the application was built successfully.